# how to redirect www and non www to https for specific domain using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

I need to redirect www and non www to https. I have looked everywhere on stackoverflow but can't find quite what I'm looking for.

The rules are:

- example.com and www.example.com and https://example.com
  must redirect to https://www.example.com
- It **must** match the domain and extension example.com. It **cannot** be a wild card which also
  matches abc.com or 123.com or example.net or anything else
- It **must** match for www subdomains only. It **cannot** be a wild card which
  also matches sub.example.com or thisisademo.example.com

I currently have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However if someone enters www.example.com it still goes to the http version instead of https.

**What I think I actually need here is RewriteCond regex to match exactly and only "example.com" and "www.example.com"**

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the following rule to redierct non-www or www to https://www in just one redirection

```
#redirect http non-www to https://www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
#redirect https non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Clear your browser's cache before testing this rule.

Comment: Unfortunately this still redirects domains that are not "example.com" and also redirects subdomains that are not "www.".

It should only redirect exactly example.com or www.example.com.

Comment: @Nhiik : I have updated the rule, replace **example.com** with **yourdomain.com** in RewriteCond and replace **www.example.com** with **www.yourdomain.com** in the Rule's target

Comment: Thanks but still not specific enough. It's redirecting to https but it's scope is still too wide. If I type test.example.com it still gets redirected to https://www.example.com. This shouldn't happen. Also if I CNAME example.net or testurl.com to the server it still gets redirected to https://www.example.com. This shouldn't happen. Only www subdomain and base domain of example.com should go through.

Answer (score 2):

This is the only way it works for me - with `!on` instead of `off` and with `%{ENV:HTTPS}` instead of `%{HTTPS}`:

```
  #non-www. http to www. https
  RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?yourdomain\.com$
  RewriteRule (.*) https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

  #non-www. https to www. https
  RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain\.com$
  RewriteRule (.*) https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#First rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use the correct one (i.e. www.)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#Now, rewrite to HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still redirects domains that are not "example.com" and also redirects subdomains that are not "www.".

It should only redirect exactly example.com or www.example.com.