# Point DNS to SSL CNAME heroku - godaddy

Tags: ssl, heroku, dns

I've successfully added a cert with lets encrypt. Now I'm trying to point my DNS to the new heroku CNAME. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong because when I try to get to my app I get the `This site can’t provide a secure connection` error. How do I point the CNAME to the DNS?

This is currently what I have a Go Daddy

[image]

Here is what I have on heroku:

[image]

Here is my forwarding.

[image]

When I type `lockdownjobs.com` in the browser I get a not secure error. So what do I do? any help would be great!

Comment: how do you redirect to https if the user types www.lockdownjobs.com

Comment: i did the same but not working..only if go to the https directly i am getting secure connection otherwise the normal www.domainname.com gets loaded

Comment: @zerocon I've tried so many things, and I don't think it can be done with godaddy. The www.lo... will always load without https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly pointed the domain (by the looks of it) This is what I see when I navigate to the page and the certificate is valid and working;

[image: webpage]

If you are still getting an error I suspect you have the DNS cached - if your accessing from a windows machine - from a command prompt do; `ipconfig /flushdns` if its a linux machine restart your dns resolver and try again.

When I lookup the domain details I see the following;

```
[root@vm0 ~]# host lockdownjobs.com.herokudns.com
lockdownjobs.com.herokudns.com has address 54.235.210.130
lockdownjobs.com.herokudns.com has address 54.225.186.255
lockdownjobs.com.herokudns.com has address 23.23.128.123
lockdownjobs.com.herokudns.com has address 23.23.117.228
lockdownjobs.com.herokudns.com has address 54.235.212.238
lockdownjobs.com.herokudns.com has address 54.235.135.158
lockdownjobs.com.herokudns.com has address 50.19.93.247
lockdownjobs.com.herokudns.com has address 23.23.223.197

[root@vm0 ~]# host lockdownjobs.com
lockdownjobs.com has address 50.63.202.15

[root@vm0 ~]# host www.lockdownjobs.com
www.lockdownjobs.com is an alias for www.lockdownjobs.com.herokudns.com.
www.lockdownjobs.com.herokudns.com has address 54.235.212.238
www.lockdownjobs.com.herokudns.com has address 184.72.248.171
www.lockdownjobs.com.herokudns.com has address 23.21.77.86
www.lockdownjobs.com.herokudns.com has address 107.21.206.81
www.lockdownjobs.com.herokudns.com has address 23.23.128.123
www.lockdownjobs.com.herokudns.com has address 54.235.210.130
www.lockdownjobs.com.herokudns.com has address 23.23.117.228
www.lockdownjobs.com.herokudns.com has address 54.243.85.55
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended up getting it working after I posted this.

Comment: @user3788685 how do you redirect to https if the user types www.lockdownjobs.com

Comment: that you need to do via your cpanel or your `.htaccess` file - its a re-write rule - have a look at; https://stackoverflow.com/a/37109808/3788685